# How to change toolbar layout in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Let's say I have 3 toolbars toolBarA, toolBarB and toolBarC. toolbarA and toolBarB are in top row. toolBarC is in the second row. Now I have added toolBarD. It is automatically placed after toolBarC in second row, but I want it to be placed in first row, after toolBarB.

Now, if drag the toolBarD to the desired location in Qt Creator, everything looks fine, but when I run the project, the toolBarD is always placed after toolBarC in the second row.

How to make it stay where I want? I have tried rebuilding whole project but that doesn't change anything.

Here is what it looks like
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Did you run qmake before rebuilding?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Qt. In Qt Creator I used Build->Rebuild all (I am using Polish version so maybe original text is different; icon with two crossed hammers). I am not sure if this involves running qmake.

Comment: Yes, this invokes qmake, and QtCreator also does wen you compile normal or click the run button after you changes some source code

Comment: And it would help if you add some screenshots of your problem (paste links to image if you arent't allowed to poste images)

Comment: @msrd0: In my experience, qmake is not always invoked after a change to a .ui file. Perhaps I have not set my project up correctly. But it's worth trying -- just right-click on the project and select "Run qmake" before building.

Comment: @TonyK If you click Rebuild, qmake will be automatically called.

Comment: @TonyK In practise using QtCreator4 from Debian Wheezy package too

Comment: @TonyK I tried using "Run qmake" without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more like a workaround than a proper solution, but it works.

The order in which toolbars are created makes a difference. Qt Creator will not change the order automatically. To trick Qt Creator that toolBarD was added right after toolBarB and before toolBarC you need to close the Creator and open .ui file inside a text editor and locate following block.

```
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBarD">
     ...
  </widget>
```

Now you have to cut it and paste it somwhere between block resposible for creation of toolBarB and toolBarD. For example, like this:

```
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBarB">
     ...
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBarD">
     ...
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="toolBarC">
     ...
  </widget>
```

Save the file and reopen the project inside Creator. toolBarD should be now placed right after toolBarB.